# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

Tags: java, android, mobile, classcastexception, listadapter

i am using a BaseExpandableListAdapter as follows. where instead of passing a list, i am directly passing a View to be a child data. and the child count is always returned as 1. as there is only one view per heading.

```
public class TaxAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

    private Context _context;
    private ArrayList<String> _listDataHeader; 
    private HashMap<String, View> _listDataChild;


    public TaxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> taxListDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, View> taxListDataChild) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = taxListDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = taxListDataChild;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
         return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
         return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition));
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
         return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LinearLayout earningsContainer = new LinearLayout(_context);
            LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity)_context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_tax_explv_title,
                    earningsContainer, false);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.explvTaxTitleText)).setText(headerTitle);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        return (View)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

and the data being passed from the activity is as follows -

```
    ArrayList<String> TaxListDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String, View> TaxListDataChild = new HashMap<String, View>();

TaxListDataHeader.add("Movie Shows");
TaxListDataChild.put("Movie Shows", moviesContainerView);
TaxListDataHeader.add("Theatre Shows");
TaxListDataHeader.add("Theatre Shows", theatreContainerView);
```

movieContainerView and theareContainerView are the two custom inflated linear layouts.like this

```
LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_movie_data,
                movieMainContainer, false);

        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtEmpInfoPopUpTitle)).setText(key);
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtEmpInfoPopUpValue)).setText(value);
        return row;
```

i am getting the error as in the title, but the logs do not specify any file name as such.
Please suggest where the error might be occuring. Please suggest what can be done.

**EDIT:**
This is the stack trace

```
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074): Process: com.synthesize.paysal, PID: 5074
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1183)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1149)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1226)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:326)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT:**
i have tried to wrap the linear layout with a list view like this,

> TaxListDataChild.put("Theatre Show", (new
>   ListView(context)).addView(theatrerowContainer,
>   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

but it seems that the second parameter is void.

I am populating the "new Linearlayout" (earningsContainer) in the xml like this with other linear layout rows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < taxMainObject.getTaxEarnings().size(); i++) {
        earningsContainer.addView(getTaxEarningsRow(taxMainObject
                    .getTaxEarnings().get(i)));
            totalEarnings += taxMainObject.getTaxEarnings().get(i)
                    .getTotalAmount();
        }
        earningsContainer.addView(getTaxTotalRow("GROSS TOTAL SALARY",
                totalEarnings + ""));
```

and the xml for the rows is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee" >


   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTotalText"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#736F6E"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTotalValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#736F6E"
             android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project? In Eclipse, it often happens that R file is not updated after changing resources, which results in IDs referring unexpected Views, hence the classcast exception. Still, you must provide logs. If you can't notice problem in log, does not mean other won't notice it too. Downvote for now.

Comment: @GabeSechan, .. added the stack trace..

Comment: @Marius .. added stack trace

Comment: Find the line where it crashes. Add `Log.d(TAG, "line number");`.Specifically, I suggest you start with `if(convertView==null)..` part.

Comment: @Marius `07-17 23:39:09.014: D/TaxAdapter(5195): before convertView null check
07-17 23:39:09.024: D/TaxAdapter(5195): in convertView null check
07-17 23:39:09.024: D/TaxAdapter(5195): after convertView null check`  these are the logs before the if condition .. inside and then after if(convertView==null), seems to run through that part, but printed only once, may be only for the first child.

Comment: Can you show layout files you use?

Comment: @Marius posted layout file in the edit

Comment: need help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951608/java-lang-classcastexception-android-view-viewgrouplayoutparams-cannot-be-cast

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not related to your java but i still got same error. I had "extends AppCompatActivity" in my class but when i replaced it with "Extends Activity" Error was resolved. Hope this is helpful for someone else, as i was stuck for three hours on this. Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

android.widget.ListView$LayoutParams is subclass of android.widget.ViewGroup$LayoutParams while android.widget.AbsListView is also subclass of same one i.e sibling relationship hence type casting will throw an exception.
Reference

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.LayoutParams.html

This suggests you can't pass a view directly as a child to listview adapter instead try passing Hashmap and inflate the view dynamically. 
Try this :

```
   @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
 }
```

Where listDataHeader is a hashmap passed to adapter like

```
public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}
```

(Passed HashMap Instead of View)

Comment: I think you are doing a mistake at line:

TaxListDataChild.put("Theatre Show", (new ListView(context)).addView(theatrerowContainer, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

Here you are trying to set the size before you add the view to a layout.
Do it like this, 

LayoutParams lp = fooView.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = 123;
lp.height = 456;
fooView.requestLayout();

Then add this view to TaxListDataChild.

Comment: I am doing - 
`LayoutParams lp = earningsContainer.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        lp.width = android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        earningsContainer.requestLayout();`
where earningsContainer is 
`ListView earningsContainer = new ListView(context);`
but i get a nullPointerexception while doing getLayoutParams()

Comment: Have you declared earningsContainer layout in your xml file?